# How do I make my own arrows?

Tags: everquest-2

Is it possible to make your own arrows? If so, what kinds of arrows are player-crafted? What are the ingredients? What are the prerequisites for doing so?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Tradeskill Class Tree](http://eq2.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Tradeskilling), with
Archetype: Artisan;
Class: Outfitter;
Subclass: Armorer;
You can produce Metal weaponry and throwing weapons. Weaponsmiths make metal weapons, leather weapons, and metal ranged weapons (Thrown only). An arrow is not throw only, thus you can't craft them with this skillset.

However,
Archetype: Craftsman;
Class: Woodworkers;
Subclass: Fletchers;
Can make their own arrows,

Comment: @antony.trupe good catch, I've updated the answer